# PHP echo javascript to change iframe source

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have a text input search form for support tickets.  If the user inputs a ticket id (checked using a PHP if statement), the background color of the search box is changed to yellow (using a PHP echo) to highlight the search text entered.  This part works.

I would like to also change the source value of an iframe as part of the PHP if condition like this:

```
    <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="ticket" id="ticket" placeholder="Ticket" value="<?php echo $this->state->ticket;?>" class="input-mini search-query" onchange="document.adminForm.submit();"
        <?php if ($this->state->ticket != "")
            {
            echo 'style="background-color: yellow;"';
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'document.getElementById("ticketIframe").contentWindow.document.location.href="http://myurl.com"';
            echo '</script>';       
            }?>/>
    </td>
```

The javascript function (document.getElementById...) displays on the page rather than executing.  I tried a simple javascript alert, but got the same result.

Suggestions?

Comment: id say the poor browser gave up trying to correct the code. Close your input `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to close the input tag before you insert script tag. You simply are generating invalid html that looks like:

```
<input <script></script> />
```

You get unexpected results when html is invalid

Comment: thats not valid html

Comment: @Dagon isn't that what i said?

Comment: sorry, i thought that was what you suggested changing it to

Comment: Closing the input made a javascript alert work properly, thank you, but my iframe source is still not working. Ideas?

Comment: Is the iframe src on same domain as page? Would throw error in your console if it isn't. If all you want is to change url....change the actual iframe element `src` instead of trying to go inside it

Comment: I tried the document.getElementById("ticketIframe").src="http..." but nothing shows up in my iframe.  Here is the iframe element within a div:  <div id="ticket_bottom" style="height: 100%; border-top: 4px solid #3a79be; position: relative;">
 <iframe id="ticketIframe" src="" width="800px" height="400px" frameborder="0" style="margin-left: 100px;margin-top: 10px;" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>
</div>

Comment: and, yes, the iframe src is on the same domain.

Comment: when do you call this? If it's before element exists will fail. Code either needs to be after html it references or in a page load handler

Comment: That was it @charlietfl, bad timing on my calling the function before it existed.  Thanks.